# Merge almost identical rows after removing nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like,

```
pri_col col1 col2        Date
     r1    3    4  2020-09-10
     r1    4    1  2020-09-11
     r1    2    7  2020-09-12
     r1    6    4  2020-09-13
```

Note: There are many more unique values in 'pri_col' column. This is just a sample here. So I'm giving  single value. Also, for a single value of 'pri_col' the value of 'Date' will be unique always.
I need the dataframe like,

```
pri_col col1_2020-09-10 col1_2020-09-11 col1_2020-09-12 col1_2020-09-13 col2_2020-09-10 col2_2020-09-11 col2_2020-09-12 col2_2020-09-13
     r1               3               4               2               6               4               1               7               4
```

According to a previous solution, I have tried this solution:

```
df = (df.reset_index()
        .melt(id_vars=['index','pri_col','Date'], 
              var_name='cols',
              value_name='val')
        .pivot(index=['index','pri_col'],
               columns=['cols','Date'],
               values='val'))
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index(level=1).rename_axis(None)
print (df)
```

But this is the resulting dataframe:

```
pri_col col1_2020-09-10 col1_2020-09-11 col1_2020-09-12 col1_2020-09-13 col2_2020-09-10 col2_2020-09-11 col2_2020-09-12 col2_2020-09-13
     r1               3             NaN             NaN             NaN               4             NaN             NaN             NaN
     r1             NaN               4             NaN             NaN             NaN               1             NaN             NaN
     r1             NaN             NaN               2             NaN             NaN             NaN               7             NaN
     r1             NaN             NaN             NaN               6             NaN             NaN             NaN               4
```

How do I solve the issue?

Also, [I had asked a question recently that may sound similar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63931964/create-columns-for-pandas-dataframe-according-to-value-of-other-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `pandas.DataFrame.set_index` with `unstack`:

```
new_df = df.set_index(['pri_col', 'Date']).unstack()
new_df.columns = ["%s_%s" % (i, j) for i, j in new_df.columns]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
         col1_2020-09-10  col1_2020-09-11  col1_2020-09-12  col1_2020-09-13  \
pri_col                                                                       
r1                     3                4                2                6   

         col2_2020-09-10  col2_2020-09-11  col2_2020-09-12  col2_2020-09-13  
pri_col                                                                      
r1                     4                1                7                4
```